# TFS Build Definition using a decoupled Design

Tags: wcf, tfs, inversion-of-control, ninject, build-dependencies

We have an WCF service on our TFS build server that has a decoupled design. I am trying to determine on how we can move our decoupled assemblies into the published websites/bin folder automatically since the compiler does not see a dependency. We use Ninject to handle our dependency injection so the compiler does not know that says assembly x is reliant on assembly y. So the bin just contains our interface assemblies for our service and not our concrete implementations. Is there a way to handle that with a build definition update? If so how would we accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option is to create a "deployment" msbuild proj file with custom Targets you can run at the end of your build pass.  This proj file would contain CopyFile tasks to copy/move everything you want from the standard locations in $(OutDir) into a deployment image structure.

Here's a walk through from MSDN that shows how to create a custom MSBuild project file:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171479(v=VS.90).aspx